want to create an archived section based on the expiry date
There are couple of listings and they have an end date set with them . I actually wanted to create a seperate route for the archived section, so basically whichever listing crosses the end date they must be shown in archived section
this is the main route which shows all the listings
<div class="container">
  <div class="row allcards mt-4">
    <% for(let listing of allListings){%>
    <div class="card p-3 justify-center items-center" style="width: 18rem">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="/listings/<%= listing._id %>" class="listing-link">
          <h5 class="card-title"><%= listing.title%></h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            current installment: <span id="input" value=""></span> <br />
            <span id="targetDate"
              >commenced month: <%= listing.startDate ?
              listing.startDate.toLocaleDateString() : "N/A" %></span
            >
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%}%>
  </div>
</div>


What expiry date,  there is no mention of it in the code you provided? "Create an archived section" where, in your html, in your database, in your garden shed? Do you want to your query to filter out expired listings? Please provide more details to clarify your problem otherwise it will be difficult to help you. Read How do I ask a good question?.

i want to show the expired listings on a different navbar option called as the "archived" so that if u access it you can find out the expired listings.
i have given the same route for that archived section as well. when i render this page through the archived section i have to find the expired listing and when i render the page through listings section it must show the active listings. I'm only used to create a "section" only in html and not anywhere else

Why not filter the array server side and just pass the listings that meet the condition and for the archived section just the expired ones? Instead if you really want it to be done in the template just say something like <% if(listing.startDate < Date.now()) %>print all listings in here<% } %> and replace Date.now() with whatever the endDate is.

i solved it
i just had to assign the Date.now() to a constant and then use the filter
<% const da=new Date() %>
<% if(listing.endDate < da %>
